# Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have a server with Exchange 2007 installed and I want to move over to Exchange 2010, I want to install Exchange 2010 onto a new server, what is the best way of moving all mailboxes and config over to the new Exchange 2010 server? Both would be on the same LAN in the same domain. I've yet to install Exchange 2010 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than reinventing the wheel... by far the best source of information is of course at [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/) - in this case:

- [Upgrade to Exchange 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa998604.aspx)
- [Upgrade from Exchange 2007 Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee332345.aspx).
- [Move Mailboxes from Exchange 2007 Servers to Exchange 2010 Servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd638192.aspx)